# my program force closes . FATAL EXCEPTION :main please see LogCat and code below

Tags: java, android, forceclose

the logcat shows something like button does not exist,but i couldn't find any mistake there.
The app force closes when i click the flashlight button in the main activity page.
I am new to android programming. please help.

LogCat:

```
 02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit/com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit.FlashlightActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Button does not exist
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Button does not exist
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setButton(AlertController.java:288)
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.AlertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.java:161)
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit.FlashlightActivity.onCreate(FlashlightActivity.java:42)
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-04 21:36:29.182: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  ... 11 more
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#151515"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:focusable="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/flashButton"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:background="@drawable/flashlight"
        android:contentDescription="@string/flashlighticon"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/flashlight" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/convertorButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/flashButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/converter"
        android:contentDescription="@string/convertericon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mglassButton"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/compassButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mirrorButton"
        android:background="@drawable/mglass"
        android:contentDescription="@string/mglassicon" />

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/bubbleButton"
         android:layout_width="60dip"
         android:layout_height="60dip"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/convertorButton"
         android:layout_below="@+id/flashButton"
         android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
         android:background="@drawable/bubble"
         android:contentDescription="@string/bubbleicon" />

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/compassButton"
         android:layout_width="60dip"
         android:layout_height="60dip"
         android:layout_above="@+id/mirrorButton"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/flashButton"
         android:background="@drawable/compass"
         android:contentDescription="@string/compassicon" />

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/mirrorButton"
         android:layout_width="60dip"
         android:layout_height="60dip"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bubbleButton"
         android:layout_below="@+id/bubbleButton"
         android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
         android:background="@drawable/mirror"
         android:contentDescription="@string/mirroricon" />

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/timerButton"
         android:layout_width="60dip"
         android:layout_height="60dip"
         android:layout_above="@+id/bubbleButton"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/calcButton"
         android:background="@drawable/timer"
         android:contentDescription="@string/timericon" />

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/calcButton"
         android:layout_width="60dip"
         android:layout_height="60dip"
         android:layout_above="@+id/mirrorButton"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:background="@drawable/calculator"
         android:contentDescription="@string/calcicon" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/flashButton"
         android:layout_below="@+id/flashButton"
         android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/flashlighticon"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView4"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/compassButton"
         android:layout_below="@+id/compassButton"
         android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/compassicon"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView6"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/calcButton"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/calcicon"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView7"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mglassButton"
         android:layout_below="@+id/mglassButton"
         android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/mglassicon"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView8"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView7"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mirrorButton"
         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/mirroricon"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timerButton"
         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/timerButton"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/timericon"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/convertericon"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView5"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/bubbleicon"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        flashlightButton();
        calculatorButton();
        bubbleButton();
    }

    private void flashlightButton()
    {  ImageButton flButton= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.flashButton);
        flButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,FlashlightActivity.class));

            }
        });
    }

        private void calculatorButton()
        {  ImageButton flButton= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.calcButton);
            flButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,CalculatorActivity.class));

                }
            });
       }

        private void bubbleButton()
        {  ImageButton flButton= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bubbleButton);
            flButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,BubbleActivity.class));

                }
            });
        }

    /*@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    } */


}
```

activity_flashlight.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".FlashlightActivity" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/flashlight_off"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

FlashlightActivity.java

```
package com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
//import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class FlashlightActivity extends Activity  {
ImageButton switchButton;

private Camera camera;
private boolean isFlashOn;
private boolean hasFlash;
Parameters params;
MediaPlayer mp;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flashlight);
    switchButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSwitch);
    // First check if device is supporting flashlight or not        
    hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    if (!hasFlash) {
        // device doesn't support flash
        // Show alert message and close the application
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(FlashlightActivity.this)
                .create();
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!");
        alert.setButton(0,"OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // closing the application
                finish();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
        return;
    }

    // get the camera
    getCamera();

    // displaying button image
    toggleButtonImage();


    // Switch button click event to toggle flash on/off
    switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isFlashOn) {
                // turn off flash
                turnOffFlash();
            } else {
                // turn on flash
                turnOnFlash();
            }
        }
    });
}


// Get the camera
private void getCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


 // Turning On flash
private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
       // playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }

}


// Turning Off flash
private void turnOffFlash() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
   //     playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }
}
/*
 * Toggle switch button images
 * changing image states to on / off
 * */
private void toggleButtonImage(){
    if(isFlashOn){
        switchButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.flashlight_on);
    }else{
        switchButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.flashlight_off);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // on pause turn off the flash
    turnOffFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // on resume turn on the flash
    if(hasFlash)
        turnOnFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // on starting the app get the camera params
    getCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // on stop release the camera
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}

/*

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.flashlight, menu);
    return true;
} */
```

}

manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit.FlashlightActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_flashlight" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit.CalculatorActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_calculator" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit.TimerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_timer" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit.BubbleActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bubble" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What is at line 42 of `FlashlightActivity`? Also, you might want to try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: Have u added the flashlight activity in manifest file ?

Comment: i've tried cleaning my project.i have added the manifest file. please see if there is any correction.

Comment: `alert.setButton(0` why don't you read the documentation for that method, since the error is an illegalargumentexception, chances are the documentation defines what values are legal for the arguments of this method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this section

```
alert.setButton(0,"OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // closing the application
            finish();
        }
    });
```

to

```
alert.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // closing the application
            finish();
        }
    });
```

The error appears because the value 0 is [unknown to the method you're using](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html#BUTTON_POSITIVE).

Comment: you're welcome! Mark it as closed then, if you please

Comment: how do I do that? i'm not familiar with this. sorry.

Comment: It's simple, @nandu: next to my answer there should be a transparent check mark. Choose it to mark the answer as accepted (you can also read this topic to get to know a bit more about the procedure: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what the doc says,

This method was deprecated in API level 3.
Use setButton(int, CharSequence, android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener) with BUTTON_POSITIVE

so instead of passing the int (0) directly, you should use DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE. Also, you can directly use

```
alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // closing the application
            finish();
        }
    });
```